# asp.net mvc FileStreamResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**First part of question:**

I have information in DB and I want to get it from db and save it as `.txt` file to client.

I have done it with Regular asp.net. but in mvc not yet. My information is not an image. This information about peoples

I watched to [This site](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files)

**Second part of question:**

I want to download file to client. There is not problem when downloading one file, but I want to download 3 file at once time with 1 request. But it could not be done. So I decided to create zip file and generate link. When user will click to link it will download to user.

What you think? Is it good to do it with this way?

**Third part of question:**(new)

How i can delete old .zip files from catalog after succes download? or another way. Lets say with service which will run on server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could have the following controller action which will fetch the information from the database and write it to the Response stream allowing the client to download it:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    string info = Repository.GetInfoFromDatabase();
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(info);
    return File(data, "text/plain", "foo.txt");
}
```

and in your view provide a link to this action:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Downoad file", "Download") %>
```

Comment: yes i checked it. But Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes() accepts string as string. but my Result from Repository.GetInfoFromDatabase(); will not simple string. it can be info as FirstName, LastName, Patronymic ...

Comment: @AEMLoviji, in this case you need to use a service layer. This service layer will invoke your repository method and generate a string or whatever format you want to send the information to the client from the model. Then your controller will call the service layer method which will return the string and stream to the client.

Comment: yes it is simple but not good way. i think so. is there any other way to convert IEnumreable to byte[]?

Comment: @AEMLoviji, no, there isn't as it makes no sense. You need to write the conversion/serialization of your model objects to a byte array manually or use one of the standard formats for which you already have built-in serializers: XML, JSON.

Comment: Darin Dimitrow can you look to second part of my question?

Comment: @AEMLoviji, yes creating a .zip file is definitely the way to go here as you cannot send multiple files in a single response.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the temporary file returned by using an Action Filter like this. Then apply the attribute to your MVC action method.

```
    public class DeleteTempFileResultFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            string fileName = ((FilePathResult)filterContext.Result).FileName;

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();

            System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        }
    }
```