# ActionResultFilter page not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, actionfilterattribute

I am developing a web site using .NET MVC3. I have a controller where I make a file download to the client.

```
    [DeleteFileAfterDownloadFilter()]
    public FileResult DownloadVersion(int VersionID)
    { 
        //staff to get the tempZipFile    
        return File(tempZipFile, "zip", "file.zip"); 
    }
```

what I like to do is to delete the file after downloading this file. I figured that I can use `ActionFilterAttribute`. So I wrote the class below:

```
public class DeleteFileAfterDownloadFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string fileName = ((FileStreamResult)filterContext.Result).FileDownloadName;
        File.Delete(fileName);
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

I guess I have 2 problems here. 
First one is that when I run this thing it gives me the error of `".../Company/DownloadVersion?versionID=2057"` page could not be found. What is the way to make it work?

And the second problem is that as you might have realized `"((FileStreamResult)filterContext.Result).FileDownloadName"` is probably not the filePath that I want to delete. It should be the "tempZipFile" local variable in controller. But I don't know how to pass that value to this event.

Comment: thanks for the corrections, makes it more readable.

Comment: And the PageNotFound is caused by the filter (ie download is Ok without it) ?

Comment: no download is taking place.

Comment: ain't no one know anything about this topic? :( im stuck here..

Comment: You can verify the fileName part with a debugger or by logging. We have too few details to understand the routing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave your filter a spin and (after corrections) it produces a nasty COM error.

This is because the async nature of the the operation: `OnResultExecuted` is your last chance to do something but this happens when the response (with the filename but not the file itself) has been send back to the client. When the client (browser) then starts the download a Not Found error or worse is produced.

In other words, your approach looks nice but it won't work.

Some rough ideas for a solution:

- make sure your server side files have unique names and a reliable timestamp
- use a background process to periodically clean them up, or
- clean up old file every time you prepare a new one

---

I changed your filter like this:

```
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {            
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

        var r = filterContext.Result as FilePathResult; // not FileContent           
        string fileName =
           filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(r.FileName);            
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
    }
```

---

Update :

Thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510933/60761), the following should work:

```
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {            
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

        var r = filterContext.Result as FilePathResult; // not FileContent           
        string fileName =
           filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(r.FileName);   

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();

        System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, what if around the File.Delete method I check if the file is busy or not? if during sending the file to the client the file is kept busy on server side i guess my approach would work, otherwise it is still a problem to periodically clean them up since i wouldn't know  if the file is still being downloaded or not. And waiting until a new file needs to be downloaded is not a good approach either since it would overload my server. because the files those need to be downloaded can be around 2-3 gb. I don't want to store them.

Comment: Thanks again, I guess this flush method makes it wait until download finishes, right?

Comment: Yes, you may want to keep an eye on timeout issues.

Comment: thanks a lot for help. and what should I do to go around the page not found error? if you can help me out with that too, I will appreciate that.

Comment: I have no clue. Try to track it down and document it better (routes etc). And then maybe post a new separate question.